# Why is this Kubernetes pod not triggering our autoscaler to scale up?

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

We're running a Kubernetes cluster that has an autoscaler, which, as far as I can tell works perfectly most of the time. When we change the replica count of a given deployment that would exceed the resources of our cluster, the autoscaler catches it and scales up. Likewise we get a scale down if we need fewer resources.

That is until today when some of the pods our Airflow deployment stopped working because they can't get the resources required. Rather than triggering a cluster scale up, the pods immediately fail or are evicted for trying to ask for or use more resources than are available. See the YAML output of one of the failing pods below. The pods also never appear as `Pending`: they skip immediately from launch to their failed state.

Is there something that I'm missing in terms of some kind of retry tolerance that would trigger the pod to be pending and thus wait for a scale up?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/psp: eks.privileged
  creationTimestamp: "2019-12-02T22:41:19Z"
  name: ingest-customer-ff06ae4d
  namespace: airflow
  resourceVersion: "32545690"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/airflow/pods/ingest-customer-ff06ae4d
  uid: dba8b4c1-1554-11ea-ac6b-12ff56d05229
spec:
  affinity: {}
  containers:
  - args:
    - scripts/fetch_and_run.sh
    env:
    - name: COMPANY
      value: acme
    - name: ENVIRONMENT
      value: production
    - name: ELASTIC_BUCKET
      value: customer
    - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
      value: <redacted>
    - name: PATH_TO_EXEC
      value: tools/storage/store_elastic.py
    - name: PYTHONWARNINGS
      value: ignore:Unverified HTTPS request
    - name: PATH_TO_REQUIREMENTS
      value: tools/requirements.txt
    - name: GIT_REPO_URL
      value: <redacted>
    - name: GIT_COMMIT
      value: <redacted>
    - name: SPARK
      value: "true"
    image: dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/spark-runner:dev
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: base
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: 28Gi
      requests:
        memory: 28Gi
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /mnt/ssd
      name: tmp-disk
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: default-token-cgpcc
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  enableServiceLinks: true
  hostNetwork: true
  priority: 0
  restartPolicy: Never
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext: {}
  serviceAccount: default
  serviceAccountName: default
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  volumes:
  - emptyDir: {}
    name: tmp-disk
  - name: default-token-cgpcc
    secret:
      defaultMode: 420
      secretName: default-token-cgpcc
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: "2019-12-02T22:41:19Z"
    lastTransitionTime: "2019-12-02T22:41:19Z"
    message: '0/9 nodes are available: 9 Insufficient memory.'
    reason: Unschedulable
    status: "False"
    type: PodScheduled
  phase: Pending
  qosClass: Burstable
```

Comment: How big are your nodes? What cloud provider are you using?

Comment: We're on EKS (Amazon's turnkey Kubernetes) and our nodes are 4 CPU/30 GB. I think the reason we added the 28 GB memory requirement was to try and force this to take up a whole node.

Comment: Not all instance memory is allocatable by user pods. It could be that 28GB is just too much to fit in a node. Also, it says in the yaml `phase: Pending` ... Try lowering the memory requirement and make sure the nodes are not tainted in a way that would prevent your pods from running there.

Comment: I hadn't noticed the pending status in that output. That makes me think it is some kind of timeout or retry tolerance. We have other deployments that request 28 GB of memory, and they both run and correctly trigger scale ups, so I don't think that's the issue. This pod is also supposed to run in 2 GB — we upped it in this test for debugging — and it fails with 2 GB as well due to other resource constraints that should trigger a scale up.

Comment: May you send an output of this pod failing with 2Gb of memory requirement? Another thing is that if you want this pod to take a entire node, you should use [taints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/) for that.